# Bootstrap, fontawesome CSP not working properly

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Trying to create CSP in flask for Fontawesome css as showed below. But the icons does not display. What I am doing wrong?

```
@posts.after_request
def add_security_headers(resp):
    resp.headers['Content-Security-Policy']=('style-src \'self\' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; \
        font-src https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css;\
        script-src \'self\' https://ajax.googleapis.com  https://code.jquery.com  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com;')
    return resp
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script defer src="/assets/fa/js/brands.js"></script>
<script defer src="/assets/fa/js/solid.js"></script>
<script defer src="/assets/fa/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```

USE the js library for fontawesome 5.
additional setup will be likethis

```
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 p-1 px-2">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com">instagram</a>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 p-1 px-2">
                <i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square fa-2x"></i>
                <a href="whatsapp://">whatsapp</a>  
            </div>
```

note the **fab** class which stands for font awesome brands , **fas** for font awesome solid...

Comment: this answer does not discuss the CSP issues of the question's focus.   I am experiencing the author's problem but with a static website, so it is likely unrelated to python/flask.

Comment: ive mentioned the html analogue, wou might want to consider translating it for flask, for your needs. i also have re written the answer. if it still does not help let me know.